# Add a number value to column in SQL query using SELECT method

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have am working on adding a query that calculates tuition costs. It should do this by using the `Tuition` table which only includes the `FullTimeCost` (a static number for the student fees), and the `PerUnitCost` (the cost per credit hour).

I am trying to use a `SELECT` to return 3 more columns, 1 constant value of 12 called units, and 2 more that calculate the rest based on simple math.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to make the column `Units` have a default value of 12.

This is my code, and the issue I am having is that when I use this approach, the following formulas do not recognize the the columns being created in the previous lines.

All I need is for the 3rd Line to recognize Units so it can multiply by 12 as intended.  Also this is for school, so a comment saying just change it to 12 is not useful.

```
SELECT 
    FullTimeCost, PerUnitCost,
    12 AS Units,
    PerUnitCost * Units AS TotalPerUnitCost,
    FullTimeCost + TotalPerUnitCost AS TotalTuition
FROM
    Tuition
```

Comment: Exactly, you can't reference a column alias defined in the same SELECT list.

Comment: Either copy-and-paste the calculation from the previous row, or use a derived table or cte.

Comment: So how do I go about solving this, it has to be done using Query, it is a school assignment and I don't have the user permissions to make new tables for this assignment.

Comment: No problem, read Gordon's answer below.

Comment: Are you possibly using MySql not SQL Server?

Comment: @shawnt00 I am using SQL Server 2019 via SSMS.

Comment: After speaking with the professor apparently all he wanted was PerUnitCost * 12 AS TotalPerUnitCost, and FulltTimeCost + (PerUnitCost * 12) AS TotalTuition.  Apparently I overthought the hell out of that exercise.  On the upside I learned about things we wont get to til later in the semester lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-use a column alias in the `select`.  However, SQL Server gives you a convenient way to define the alias in the `from` clause, so you can use it:

```
SELECT t.FullTimeCost, t.PerUnitCost, v.Units,
       v2.TotalPerUnitCost,
       (t.FullTimeCost + v2.TotalPerUnitCost AS TotalTuition
FROM Tuition t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (12)) v(units) CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.PerUnitCost * v.Units)) v2(TotalPerUnitCost);
```

Comment: We're on Chapter 3 of Murachs SQL Server 2019.  That is so far beyond what we have learned thus far.  Are there simpler solutions than this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to "add" your constant as a column and then apply the calculation. Without context, a variable would also be just as simple and useful.

```
with cte as (select FullTimeCost, PerUnitCost, 12 as Units 
    from dbo.Tuition
   )
SELECT 
    FullTimeCost, PerUnitCost,
    Units,
    PerUnitCost * Units AS TotalPerUnitCost,
    FullTimeCost + TotalPerUnitCost AS TotalTuition
FROM cte
order by ...;
```

There are, of course, other ways to accomplish this. Not certain what your coursework has covered but I assume that recent topics should have provided techniques to do this.

Comment: `FROM (select *, 12 as Units from dbo.Tuition) t` if tables expressions are too advanced.

Comment: But this also has the same issue since `TotalPerUnitCost` is derived.

Comment: oops - missed the second calculation. Surely OP, with the help of course materials, can adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` as shown by Gordon's answer is the most elegant solution and also noted in the comments is another way using a *derived table*.

As you have no doubt gathered, the problem is that during query compilation, the optimizer does not "see" the calculated column aliases as it can only (generally) access columns available from tables in the `where` clause, or as shown by Gordon, using an `apply()`.

What you can also do is use a derived table, by first selecting the columns you need from your table and also adding your additional columns.

You then wrap this in parentheses - it's now a *derived table* ie, the results of the parenthesis content is itself a table available to an *outer* select.

You then use this as the *source* for an outer select which has visiblity of any additional columns you have added.

A complication with your query is that you want to add a constant value *Units* and then reference it, and *also* reference a second calculated column that makes use of Units.

I would simply use a single derived table to calculate the *TotalPerUnitCost*, you don't need Units since it's used only once.

```
select 
    FullTimeCost, PerUnitCost, TotalPerUnitCost,
    FullTimeCost + TotalPerUnitCost as TotalTuition
from (
    select FullTimeCost, PerUnitCost, TotalPerUnitCost, PerUnitCost * 12 as TotalPerUnitCost
    from Tuition
)t
```

Comment: Like I said, that wasn't allowed.  It had to be a part of the select statement.  Thank you though,